# cómo puedo vaciar un DIV o un P con javascript o Jquery pulsando un boton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

Necesitaría borrar o dejar los textos vacios de un **DIV** o un **P** al pulsar un botón de borrar.

En el siguiente codigo lo que hace es desde un **SELECT** traigo datos desde una base de datos, y al seleccionar un apellido me muestra datos en unos `<p>` con su *ID*, y al presionar el botón *borrar* me borra perfecto lo que seleccioné en **SELECT**, pero al seleccionar otro para borrar **NO ME BORRA**, quedan los datos anteriores.

¿Que estará mal?

Codigo en js

```
function EliminarSeleccionado() {
  //capta lo que selecciono
  var select = document.getElementById('buscarporapellido');
  //boton Eliminar
  var delButton = document.getElementById('btnEliminar');

  function remove() {
    value = select.selectedIndex;
    select.removeChild(select[value]);
  }
  //remueve lo seleccionado dentro del SELECT
  delButton.onclick = remove;
  //vacia el contenido de los <p>
  $("#Principalfide").empty();
  $('#PrincipalLetra').empty();

}
```

Comment: aca dejo los <p>

Comment: <p class="pprontuario text-lg-left"> Prontuario N°: <span class="badge text-lg-center text-bg-primary" id="PrincipalProntuario"></span></p>
<p class="pprontuario text-lg-left"> DNI: <span class="badge text-lg-center text-bg-primary" id="Principalfidni"></span></p>

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade lo que agregaste en los comentarios, observa bien "área de comentarios" no de código.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade lo que agregaste en los comentarios, observa bien "área de comentarios" no de código.

Comment: @JulioAndres No pongas código en los comentarios, no se ve bien. El código debe ir en la pregunta. Recuerda que pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta puedes modificarla las veces que necesites, gracias.

Comment: @JulioAndres y agrega a tu pregunta lo que nos falte para poderla reproducir bien. En este caso el HTML correspondiente al select `buscarporapellido`, el botón `btnEliminar` y el párrafo `PrincipalLetra` que no lo veo tampoco.  (y parece que sobra el párrafo `PrincipalProntuario`... o quizás ahi está el problema? que deberia ser `PrincipalLetra`?  no se)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no has puesto todo el código, ya creo haber visto lo que te ocurre.
Pones esto así:

```
delButton.onclick = remove;
```

por lo tanto estas cargándote lo que contenga ese onclick (que seguramente será una llamada a `EliminarSeleccionado()`) y al segunda vez que lo haces pues eso, ya no está.

Aparte de eso, no llamas al `remove` correctamente, debe ser con `()` al final pues es una función.

En resumen, así debería funcionarte mejor:

```
function EliminarSeleccionado() {
  //capta lo que selecciono
  var select = document.getElementById('buscarporapellido');
  //boton Eliminar
  var delButton = document.getElementById('btnEliminar');

  function remove() {
    value = select.selectedIndex;
    select.removeChild(select[value]);
  }

  //remueve lo seleccionado dentro del SELECT
  remove()

  //vacia el contenido de los <p>
  $("#Principalfidni").empty();
  $('#PrincipalLetra').empty();
}
```

pero tampoco le veo el sentido a ponerlo dentro de una funcion ahora mismo, pues puedes dejarlo así tranquilamente supongo:

```
function EliminarSeleccionado() {

  //capta lo que selecciono
  var select = document.getElementById('buscarporapellido');

  //boton Eliminar
  var delButton = document.getElementById('btnEliminar');

  // borro el option seleccionado
  value = select.selectedIndex;
  select.removeChild(select[value]);

  //vacia el contenido de los <p>
  $("#Principalfidni").empty();
  $('#PrincipalLetra').empty();
}
```

Comment: Perfecto..!!!! ahi funciono....muchas gracias @masterguru....